# Sort li by data-id of child element - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I am trying to sort an un-ordered list by the data-id attribute of a child element within each `<li>`. How do I target this element to sort by its value?

Here is my current code:

```
    $("#sort_popularity").live("click", function() {
        var listitems = list.children('li').get();

        listitems.sort(function(a, b) {
            var compA = $(a).("#subject_popularity");
            var compB = $(b).("#subject_popularity");
            return compA < compB;
        });

        $.each(listitems, function(index, item) {
            list.append(item); // (List is defined elsewhere in my code)
        });
    });
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="sort_popularity">Sort</a>

<ul>
    <li><span id="popularity" data-id="10">10</li>
    <li><span id="popularity" data-id="20">20</li>
    <li><span id="popularity" data-id="5">5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 Data Attribute Sort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560493/html5-data-attribute-sort) or [Sort list based on data attribute (using jquery metadata plugin)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4258974/1048572)

Comment: By the way, you can't have multiple elements with the same ID. You should change `id` to either `class` or `name`

Comment: Oh of course! I totally spaced on that one. If I were to use the "name" attribute, how would I select that with jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// for ASC.
var lis = $('ul li');

lis.sort(function(a, b) {
    return parseInt($('span', a).data('id'), 10) > parseInt( $('span', b).data('id'), 10);
});

$('ul').html(lis);
```

**AND**

```
// for DESC.
var lis = $('ul li');

lis.sort(function(a, b) {
    return parseInt( $('span', a).data('id'), 10) < parseInt( $('span', b).data('id'), 10);
});

$('ul').html(lis);
```

#### Note

change `id`s of `span`s, no same `id` for multiple `span` and close your `span` tag(may be typos).

Comment: I changed my id attributes to "name". It works fine in FireFox, but not in Safari. Any idea why this might be?

Comment: @Sneaksta instead of `name` change them to `class`, I think `name` is not preferred for `span`, and keep `data-id` unchanged

Comment: @Sneaksta can you make a fiddle what you've tried and share that here

Comment: Spans are not well formed. Try `<li><span class="popularity" data-id="10">10</span></li>` ... , or `<li class="popularity" data-id="10">10</li>` ... .